# character count minus HTML characters C#

Tags: c#, truncate, counting, html

I'm trying to figure out a way to count the number of characters in a string, truncate the string, then returns it. However, I need this function to NOT count HTML tags. The problem is that if it counts HTML tags, then if the truncate point is in the middle of a tag, then the page will appear broken.

This is what I have so far...

```
public string Truncate(string input, int characterLimit, string currID) {
    string output = input;

    // Check if the string is longer than the allowed amount
    // otherwise do nothing
    if (output.Length > characterLimit && characterLimit > 0) {

        // cut the string down to the maximum number of characters
        output = output.Substring(0, characterLimit);

        // Check if the character right after the truncate point was a space
        // if not, we are in the middle of a word and need to remove the rest of it
        if (input.Substring(output.Length, 1) != " ") {
            int LastSpace = output.LastIndexOf(" ");

            // if we found a space then, cut back to that space
            if (LastSpace != -1)
            {
                output = output.Substring(0, LastSpace);
            }
        }
        // end any anchors
        if (output.Contains("<a href")) {
            output += "</a>";
        }
        // Finally, add the "..." and end the paragraph
        output += "<br /><br />...<a href='Announcements.aspx?ID=" + currID + "'>see more</a></p>";
    }
    return output;
}
```

But I'm not happy with this. Is there a better way to do this? If you could provide a new solution to this, or perhaps suggestions on what to add to what I have so far, that would be great.

Disclaimer: I've never worked with C#, so I'm not familiar with the concepts related to the language... I'm doing this because I have to, not by choice.

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: You should use an actual [HTML parser](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). That is the only reliable way to perform operations on HTML that will preserve the semantic representation.

Comment: Don't forget about character entities, too: `&nbsp;`, `&#8212;`, etc. You don't want to break those in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the right tool for the problem.**

HTML is not a simple format to parse. I would advise that you use a [proven, existing parser](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) rather than rolling your own. If you know that you will only ever parse XHTML - then you could use an XML parser instead.

These are the only reliable ways to perform operations on HTML that will preserve the semantic representation.

*Don't try to use regular expressions*. HTML is not a regular language and you can only cause yourself grief and misery going in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I looked at the parser and it doesn't look trivial to use. The only thing I have against the parser is that I don't want to parse a whole HTML document... just a snippet that will be added to the page dynamically.

Comment: @Hristo: Take a look at the `DocumentElement.SelectNodes` method. You should be able to select all nodes of all types, and then use the `InnerText` property to count the number of non-HTML characters.

Comment: .. before I can use any of the html agility pack features such as `DocumentElement.SelectNodes`, I need to get it working with Microsoft Visual Web Developer. Do you have any suggestions on how to get it "installed"?